# Speed difference for bitwise operations

Tags: c

Below two code blocks calculate the Hamming distance between two integers. They are the same, but why is the first one faster than the second one on LeetCode?

Fast:

```
int hammingDistance(int x, int y) {
    int count = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 32; ++i)
    {
        count += (x&1) ^ (y&1);
        x >>= 1;
        y >>= 1;
    }
    return count;
}
```

Slow:

```
int hammingDistance(int x, int y) {
    int n = x ^ y;
    int count = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 32; ++i)
    {
        count += n & 1;
        n >>= 1;
    }
    return count;
}
```

**** **Update** ****

I have written a test code on my Mac machine:

```
#include <time.h>
#include "cstdio"

int hamm_fast(int x, int y) {
    int count = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 32; ++i)
    {
        count += (x&1) ^ (y&1);
        x >>= 1;
        y >>= 1;
    }
    return count;
}

int hamm_slow(int x, int y) {
    int n = x ^ y;
    int count = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 32; ++i)
    {
        count += n & 1;
        n >>= 1;
    }
    return count;
}

int main()
{
    clock_t begin;
    clock_t end;
    double time_spent;

    // benchmark fast
    begin = clock();
    for (int i = 0; i < 100000; ++i)
        hamm_fast(100,100);
    end = clock();
    time_spent = (double)(end - begin) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
    printf("Fast: %f ms\n", time_spent*1e3);

    // benchmark slow
    begin = clock();
    for (int i = 0; i < 100000; ++i)
        hamm_slow(100,100);
    end = clock();
    time_spent = (double)(end - begin) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
    printf("Slow: %f ms\n", time_spent*1e3);

    return 0;
}
```

And compile and run as

```
g++ ham.cpp && ./a.out
```

And the two solutions turn out to be similar. For example:

```
Fast: 7.233000 ms
Slow: 6.963000 ms
```

Actually the slow one is faster ...

Comment: What is the difference in speed?

Comment: Look at the disassembly. That's the most obvious way.

Comment: The fast one is 0 ~ 1 ms. The slow one is  4 ~ 5 ms.

Comment: That kind of difference can be accounted for by the fact that there are more operations in the latter example, or how fast the wind is blowing outside.  You will get a better benchmark result if you put the whole thing in a loop, run it 10,000 times and measure that.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I don't believe a single run of this function will be of ms order. I hope the OP does mean the looped benchmark.

Comment: @EugeneSh. There's probably all sorts of startup overhead in those two times cited.

Comment: The difference demonstrated in updated code is negligible.

Comment: I have updated the problem with a test case. Thanks for your helps!

Comment: You should at least enable optimizations (`g++ -O2 ham.cpp`).

Comment: @melpomene Yeah. But then it will be super fast, as `Fast: 0.002000 ms
Slow: 0.001000 ms`

Comment: Yes, as it should be.

Comment: Somehow your fast became slower than slow.

Comment: @EugeneSh. And this is why it's a bad idea to try and second guess how fast something will go.  Benchmarking is the only way to be sure.

Comment: I don't see any reason in this exercise anyway. I don't believe this function is a bottleneck to something. The second variant is more elegant if you ask me, and I would pick it. If you want to optimize it a bit, you can use some intrinsic `popcnt`.

Comment: @EugeneSh. Thank you. Could you post it as an answer so I will accept it. Thanks again!

Comment: Do you get the same results if you test "slow" before "fast"?

Comment: Yes, when `g++ ham.cpp`

Comment: If you want to understand how your code would translate straight into assembly you should set -O0. That will show that slow will probably be faster because in the faster you are doing there a xor and two shift inside a loop: so all time, while you have the xor outside plus a single shift inside in the slow one. When you start enabling the optimizations, that becomes more unpredictable, as the compiler will try to understand what to do...I suggest that you use g++ -Wa,-adhnl -g speed.c to see mixed c and assembly code to see what the compiler is doing.

Comment: Beware: an aggressive optimizer could remove the test loops because you pass the same values to the Hamming distance functions on each iteration and ignore the returned value — which would leave you with nothing to measure. If it were my testing, I'd have a test function containing the timing and function calls. The function call would be inside two loops, and I'd pass the two loop indexes as arguments to the function, and sum the return values, and print the sum at the end to help ensure that the functions produce the same results.  I'd also make it run for seconds, not milliseconds.

Comment: 'Tis curious this is tagged with C but you have `#include "cstdio"`.  I suppose that the 'header' `cstdio` contains `#include <stdio.h>` — but it looks as if you were thinking of coding in C++ with that name.

Comment: Both of your ways are slower than they need to be. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/109023/how-to-count-the-number-of-set-bits-in-a-32-bit-integer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I noted in a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51791590/speed-difference-for-bitwise-operations#comment90546653_51791590), you need to be careful with the benchmarking to ensure that an aggressive optimizer cannot optimize the function calls away.

An aggressive optimizer could remove the test loops because you pass the same values to the Hamming distance functions on each iteration and ignore the returned value — which would leave you with nothing to measure.

If it were my testing, I'd have a test function containing the timing and function calls. The function call would be inside two loops, and I'd pass the two loop indexes as arguments to the function, and sum the return values, and print the sum at the end to help ensure that the functions produce the same results. I'd also make it run for seconds, not milliseconds.

Here's my code.  It uses timing code available in my [SOQ](https://github.com/jleffler/soq) (Stack Overflow Questions) repository on GitHub as files `timer.c` and `timer.h` in the [src/libsoq](https://github.com/jleffler/soq/tree/master/src/libsoq) sub-directory.

```
#include "timer.h"
#include <stdio.h>

#define L1_MIN 0
#define L1_MAX 10240
#define L2_MIN 0
#define L2_MAX 10240

static int hamm_fast(int x, int y)
{
    int count = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 32; ++i)
    {
        count += (x & 1) ^ (y & 1);
        x >>= 1;
        y >>= 1;
    }
    return count;
}

static int hamm_slow(int x, int y)
{
    int n = x ^ y;
    int count = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 32; ++i)
    {
        count += n & 1;
        n >>= 1;
    }
    return count;
}

static void tester(const char *tag, int (*function)(int x, int y))
{
    Clock t;
    clk_init(&t);

    clk_start(&t);
    int sum = 0;
    for (int i = L1_MIN; i < L1_MAX; i++)
    {
        for (int j = L2_MIN; j < L2_MAX; j++)
            sum += (*function)(i, j);
    }
    clk_stop(&t);

    char buffer[32];
    int iterations = (L1_MAX - L1_MIN) * (L2_MAX - L2_MIN);
    printf("%s sum = %d (%d iterations) %s\n", tag, sum, iterations,
            clk_elapsed_us(&t, buffer, sizeof(buffer)));
}

int main(void)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        tester("Fast", hamm_fast);
        tester("Slow", hamm_slow);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The output I got on one run was:

```
Fast sum = 710934528 (104857600 iterations) 2.461100
Slow sum = 710934528 (104857600 iterations) 1.181584
Fast sum = 710934528 (104857600 iterations) 2.480401
Slow sum = 710934528 (104857600 iterations) 1.182961
Fast sum = 710934528 (104857600 iterations) 2.466685
Slow sum = 710934528 (104857600 iterations) 1.197394
Fast sum = 710934528 (104857600 iterations) 2.435806
Slow sum = 710934528 (104857600 iterations) 1.175533
Fast sum = 710934528 (104857600 iterations) 2.384162
Slow sum = 710934528 (104857600 iterations) 1.184161
Fast sum = 710934528 (104857600 iterations) 2.376042
Slow sum = 710934528 (104857600 iterations) 1.191555
Fast sum = 710934528 (104857600 iterations) 2.389027
Slow sum = 710934528 (104857600 iterations) 1.169186
Fast sum = 710934528 (104857600 iterations) 2.393707
Slow sum = 710934528 (104857600 iterations) 1.209600
Fast sum = 710934528 (104857600 iterations) 2.423526
Slow sum = 710934528 (104857600 iterations) 1.204585
Fast sum = 710934528 (104857600 iterations) 2.515968
Slow sum = 710934528 (104857600 iterations) 1.196783
```

As you can see, the 'fast' code is about twice as slow as the 'slow' code.  That's primarily because the 'fast' code is doing many more operations per loop than the 'slow' code.  The 'fast' code does 2 `&` operations, 1 `^` operation, and 2 `>>=` operations compared to 1 `&` and 1 `>>=` in the 'slow' code. But the results are apparently the same; that's the good news.  The functions are equivalent in terms of result, but not in terms of speed.

Compilation on a MacBook Pro running macOS 10.13.6 High Sierra, using GCC 8.2.0.

Compilation command line (source file `spot79.c`):

```
$ gcc -O3 -g -I./inc -std=c11 -Wall -Wextra -Werror -Wmissing-prototypes \
>     -Wstrict-prototypes spot79.c -o spot79 -L./lib -lsoq
$
```

The `timer.h` header was in the `./inc` directory and the `soq` library was in `./lib` — that's simply my build setup.